# NPM Install fails - fsevents

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, vagrant, npm-install

I'm unable to get npm installed correctly in my laravel project. I'm running laravel on a vagrant box (ubuntu-trusty-64). When I run 'npm install' I get the first error in my pastebin (linked below). I then found somewhere below that I should run it without symlinks when using a vagrant box on a windows host os so I then ran 'npm install --no-bin-links' and I was still getting the first error. So then with some help I ran 'rm -rf node_modules' then ran the 'npm install --no-bin-links' and it appears to work but hangs see second half of the pastebin.

Please help!

## pastebin: https://pastebin.com/wuRkjqi6

Update:

Just to update everyone on the status, I completely removed npm and reinstalled it following:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

for node.js 8

I then ran 'sudo npm install --no-bin-links --verbose' directly from the host vm via virtualbox bypassing the vagrant ssh; but it still bombs out on me; this time with an error. but still surrounding fsevents.

```
27990 info lifecycle vue@2.4.2~postinstall: vue@2.4.2
27991 verbose unlock done using /home/vagrant/.npm/_locks/staging-71408633a969dee2.lock for /home/vagrant/projects/MusekClub/node_modules/.staging
27992 verbose stack Error: ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rmdir '/home/vagrant/projects/MusekClub/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules'
27993 verbose cwd /home/vagrant/projects/MusekClub
27994 verbose Linux 3.13.0-125-generic
27995 verbose argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--no-bin-links" "--verbose"
27996 verbose node v8.2.1
27997 verbose npm  v5.3.0
27998 error path /home/vagrant/projects/MusekClub/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules
27999 error code ETXTBSY
28000 error errno -26
28001 error syscall rmdir
28002 error ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rmdir '/home/vagrant/projects/MusekClub/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules'
28003 verbose exit [ -26, true ]
```

Lastly I tried rebuilding the vagrant box from scratch this morning and when I re-ran 'sudo npm install --no-bin-links --verbose' from the virtualbox host I get the following:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/projects/MusekClub$ sudo npm install
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/projects/MusekClub/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/.deps/User/eshanker/Code/fsevents/lib
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rmdir '/home/vagrant/projects/MusekClub/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/.deps/Users/eshanker/Code/fsevents/lib'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2017-08-09T12_45_58_590Z-debug.log
```

I removed the standard dependencies from the default laravel 5.4 package.json file.  I then installed each one, one by one.  I found that my issue only occurs when installing the "laravel-mix": "^1.0" dependency line.

Comment: I'm having the same issue w/ this module.

Comment: Are you using vagrant as well by chance?

Comment: Yes.  I was able to get around this by removing `--no-bin-links`.  I run my vagrant machine as admin which I believe may also be a necessary component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to overcome my issue by ditching npm and utilizing yarn.  Seems to get past the fsevents module as reading it as an optional dependency.  Given what I've researched it appears that fsevents isn't supported on linux anyways.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/projects/MusekClub$ sudo yarn install
yarn install v0.27.5
    Resolving packages...
    Fetching packages...
warning fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check.
Excluding it from installation.
    Linking dependencies...
    Building fresh packages...
Done in 67.15s.
```

Answer (score 2):

`npm install --no-optional` helped me, but it is merely dodging the problem.

Comment: The --no-optional argument will prevent optional dependencies from being installed.

Answer (score 1):

Using vagrant I was able to get around this by removing `--node-bin-links` and running my vagrant box as admin.  I'm using roughly the same versions of node and npm.